# Selecting the right Linux I/O scheduler for a host equipped with NVMe SSD?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduler

We are writing a highly concurrent software in C++ for a few hosts, all equipped with a single ST9500620NS as the system drive and an Intel P3700 NVMe Gen3 PCIe SSD card for data.  Trying to understand the system more for tuning our software, I dug around the system (two E5-2620 v2 @ 2.10GHz CPUs, 32GB RAM, running CentOS 7.0) and was surprised to spot the following:

```
[root@sc2u0n0 ~]# cat /sys/block/nvme0n1/queue/scheduler 
none
```

This contradicts to everything that I learned about selecting the correct Linux I/O scheduler, such as from [the official doc on kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/block/switching-sched.txt?id=HEAD).

I understand that NVMe is a new kid on the block, so for now I won't touch the existing scheduler setting. But I really feel odd about the "none" put in by the installer.  If anyone who has some hints as to where I can find more info or share your findings, I would be grateful. I have spent many hours googling without finding anything concrete so far.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"none" (aka "noop") is the correct scheduler to use for this device.

I/O schedulers are primarily useful for slower storage devices with limited queueing (e.g, single mechanical hard drives) — the purpose of an I/O scheduler is to reorder I/O requests to get more important ones serviced earlier. For a device with a very large internal queue, and very fast service (like a PCIe SSD!), an I/O scheduler won't do you any good; you're better off just submitting all requests to the device immediately.

Comment: logically, I got what you said. Perhaps I should have made myself more clear - I didn't see this option "none" anywhere. Do I have to dig into the kernel code to find it or is it documented anywhere?

Comment: In fact, I got so curious that I downloaded the entire `linux-3.18.1.tar.xz` to my machine, `untar` the source `zx`-ed tar ball, and went into `linux-3.18.1/block`, did a `grep -i none` and reviewed the `noop-iosched.c` too. Nowhere I saw this option name `none`. Now I am even more mystified why the CentOS Anaconda installer used this seemingly undocumented name. Hey, Red Hat folks?

Comment: My loop back devices show `cat /sys/block/loop*/queue/scheduler` as `none`. Are you sure your device is recognized, connected, formatted properly and/or mounted with some file system type(ext{3,4},btrfs). From this article [Tuning i/o schedulers for ssds](http://dev.nuodb.com/techblog/tuning-linux-io-scheduler-ssds) however, should show up all the standard schedulers and a selected one. At-least it should give you an option using a different scheduler for testing purposes ?

Comment: another similar [http://serverfault.com/questions/585715/setting-i-o-scheduler-for-ssd-based-raid-array-on-ec2-instances](http://serverfault.com/questions/585715/setting-i-o-scheduler-for-ssd-based-raid-array-on-ec2-instances) may be worth looking into. Suggests installing the tuned-adm utils.

Comment: Interesting.  Are you using a machine that runs Debian or a derivative such as Ubuntu?  Of all RHEL nodes that I have access to, I don't see `/sys/block/loop*`. I do see such on a machine running Ubuntu 12.04LTS, which indeed, shows the `none`.  Yes. All devices are under heavy use (we have been running our software using these NVMe devices for sometime). They show up in e.g. `mount`, `df -h` output too. At any rate, now I know `none` is likely "poorly documented" alias for `noop`, I will accept your answer.  Thanks for sharing your experience and time!

Comment: The reason is that NVMe bypasses the scheduler. You're not using the "noop" implementation: you're not using a scheduler.

Answer (score 19):

The answer given by Sanne in the comments is correct:

"The reason is that NVMe bypasses the scheduler. You're not using the "noop" implementation: you're not using a scheduler."

noop is not the same as none, noop still performs block merging (unless you disable it with nomerges)

If you use an nvme device, or if you enable "scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=Y" at compile time or boot time, then you bypass the traditional request queue and its associated schedulers.

Schedulers for blk-mq might be developed in the future.

Comment: Now we have IO Schedulers for blk-mq something like kyber. With kyber you can achieve configurable read latency and sync writes by throttling hosts. https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/9672023/