# How can iostat utilization be 100% with a queue size of < 1

Tags: linux, performance, optimization, solid-state-drive, iostat

Consider understanding the performance of a C program which writes blocks between 12 and 16 KiB to a few files sequentially within each file.

It produces the following `iostat -x` line<sup>1</sup> from a one second interval for a disk under a fairly heavy load of ~16 KiB writes:

```
Device               w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz  aqu-sz  %util
nvme1n1          7497.00 105250.50     0.00   0.00    0.03    14.04    0.23 100.00
```

It shows 100% utilization and `aqu-sz` of 0.23. This is typical reading for this workload: the queue size generally hovers around 0.20 to 0.25 and the utilizatio is usually 100%, but for an occasional measurement interval somewhat less like 90% or 95%.

As I understand it, utilization is "the fraction of time at least 1 request was outstanding to the disk"<sup>2</sup>. So 100% means that at least 1 request was outstanding at all times. The `aqu-sz` or *average queue size*, as I understand it, is the time-averaged size of the requests outstanding queue, i.e., the average number of in-flight requests submitted to the block layer which haven't yet completed.

Something is wrong though: this reading is not consistent with these definitions. If there were at least 1 request outstanding at all times (implied by utilization 100%) then the average queue size must be *at least* 1.0, since it is never less than 1.0 at any moment.

So what's up with that?

---

<sup>1</sup> I've cut out the read and discard stats since they are both ~0 for this run.

<sup>2</sup> Unlike single-head disks, for HDDs with multiple independent heads and for modern SSDs which can both handle several outstanding requests, a utilization of 100% does not correspond to "saturated device".

Comment: How is this a programming question? Maybe check on proper site https://serverfault.com/q/1111657/115396

Comment: I'm programming a process and need to undestand its performance. This type of thing [has always been on-topic at SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), since it extends to tools used by programmers. This question might _also_ be appropriate on another stackexchange site: SO is not disjoint with e.g., serverfault and unix sites.

Comment: I suspect it is because NVMe bypasses scheduling.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27664577/1216776

Comment: I believe that means programming tools ... even if a programmer uses word to write their documentation that doesn't make questions about using word on-topic.

Comment: @tink: Actually it's any tool, if the entire condition is met.  "software tools commonly used by programmers; **and is a practical, answerable problem that is UNIQUE to software development**"   This question is not unique to software development; it would arise commonly in server management.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: The overlap between SO and SF allows asking programming questions on SF if they are about automating server management functions.  A question about writing an `iostat` tool would be on-topic on both sites.  Use of the existing `iostat` tool is on-topic on SF but off-topic here.

Comment: @tink Do you mean that `any` questions about the usage of word is off-topic here ?

Comment: @Philippe -no, if you were using VBA or some such you'd be alright...

Comment: @tink VBA is not in the category of `usage` of word, because it's a programming language.

Comment: Nuh, for that I'd go to [su] ;)

Comment: And which non-programming uses of word would see as fitting here? But that may be a better fit on meta, rather than in the comments to this rightfully closed thread ;)

Comment: As you mention SU, I'll rephrase my last question : if you have a question on keyboard shortcuts in Word, and you estimate you have 90% of chance to get an anwser in SO, but 10% of chance to get an answer in SU, are you still going to SU ?

Comment: Absolutely, as a keyboard shortcut in word has nothing to do w/ programming. Just like I wouldn't ask my physio about bikes, even though I know he is very knowledgeable.